# How to add a once only section and section titles to a UITableView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I need to add another section to my tableview which will occur once at the top of the table. I also want to use a custom view so I can format the contents nicely.

In the picture below you can see I have section headers and rows underneath each.

I've tried several times, but I'm a little confused as to how many sections I should have and the logic to show all the rows I need. To further complicate matters I also display a single row with a single section, with text saying there are no rows available. In this case I want to show my new section and that text.

[image]

Here’s my code..

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    int count = [sectionTitles count];
    if (count == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return count;
    }
}
```

//

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:
          (NSInteger)section {
    int count = 0;
    if (sectionRowCounts.count != 0) {
        NSString *title = [sectionTitles objectAtIndex:section];
        count = [[sectionRowCounts objectForKey:title] intValue];
    }
    return (count ? count : 1);
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:
     (NSInteger)section {
    NSString *title = @"";
    if (sectionTitles.count != 0 ) {
        title = [sectionTitles objectAtIndex:section];
    }
    return title;
}
```

//

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:
   (NSInteger)section {
     if (sectionTitles.count == 0 ) {
         UIView *customView = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];
        return customView;
    } 

    HeaderSectionReportView *customView = [[[HeaderSectionReportView alloc] 
       initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 360.0, 20.0)] autorelease];

    // create the button object
    UILabel * headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    headerLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, 0.0, 100.0, 20.0); 
    headerLabel.text = [sectionTitles objectAtIndex:section];
    [customView addSubview:headerLabel];
    [headerLabel release];

    return customView;
}

- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 20.0;
}
```

//

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
           cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell1;
    if(rowSections.count == 0) {

        cell1 = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:
             UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil] autorelease];

        UIView *view = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];
        view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell1.selectedBackgroundView = view;

        cell1.textLabel.text = @"No transactons found";
        return cell1;
    }

    NSString *strRowSection = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i-%i", 
         indexPath.section, indexPath.row];
    NSInteger intDBRow = [rowSections indexOfObject:strRowSection];
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ReportCell";

    ReportCell *cell = (ReportCell *) [tableView 
          dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

//

```
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] 
         loadNibNamed:@"ReportCell" owner:nil options:nil];

        for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects) {
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
                cell = ((ReportCell *) currentObject);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    NSString *desc = [[transactionsArray objectAtIndex:intDBRow] 
            objectForKey:@"desc"];
    cell.descriptionValue.text = desc;

    UIView *view = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = view;

    return cell;

}
```

//

```
- (void) populateDataSource {

    int sectionIncr = -1;
    int rowIncr = 0;

    sectionTitles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:nil];
    sectionRowCounts = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    rowSections = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:nil];

    NSMutableArray *arrayTmp= [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    //populate array

    self.transactionsArray = arrayTmp;
    [arrayTmp release];

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you could certainly just add another section at the beginning with a custom view associated with it there is another option. You can assign a custom view to the UITableView property 'tableHeaderView', see [tableHeaderView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/tableHeaderView) in the Apple documentation.